# Complete animation on class removal

Tags: html, css, animation, css-transitions

I have something similar to this in my project:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AqfCg

If you click toggle, animation starts nice, but when you click it again, animation is stopped and rotation is set to 0 instantly. Is there any way  I can make animation stop slowly or at least wait until is rotated to 0?

ps. I'm **not** looking for javascript/jquery solution and I want it to be only CSS3+HTML (I used jquery only to demonstrate what am I trying to achieve)

Comment: I doubt this is possible without JS... I do, however, have a solution if you were to use transitions rather than animations though.

Comment: @JoshC If I can do infinite rotation with transition, I'm okay with that, please share if you have solution. Thanks!

Comment: But u still use jquery to toggle the class right?

Comment: @MarkusKottländer I'm actually using angular, I used jQuery only on codepen to demonstrate what am I doing.

Comment: So toggling the class is the only thing you want to do with javascript?

Comment: @MarkusKottländer This is my plan, but if I won't be able to do it with CSS only. I'll just use javascript.

Comment: Solution is coming...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:**
There you have it!
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/amIhC

This is mainly what you want, just with css (and toggling the class).